# Calling Webservice in dll and then calling dll from asp.net webform generate error

Tags: web-services, dllexport

[This image is calling webservice object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8uMn.png)

[This is app.config settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPh66.png)

[Here is webform where i call this method to save data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AprtW.png)

[This error Appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZKIa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check `app.config`. Set port address after localhost.